# How to get production key for google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

When i am exporting apk the google map does not shown in my application. I need to put production key for exporting apk. I don't have any idea about how to get production key. If any one knows answer just share with me. Pls, give me a step by step solution. I already tried with below link.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039072/while-make-sign-apk-of-google-map-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-s/16080200#16080200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally there are two keys debug key and release key. while signing app, you want to use release key. For that you want to compare that with signed apk

Step 1:

Say for example your apk name is A and you are signing and creating a keystore for A.apk ie A.keystore will be created in some drive location.Let's consider it in E drive.

step 2:

Now locate to jdk in C drive(Considering for windows and assigning C drive)

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin>keytool -list -v  -keystore E:\A.keystore -alias A

So it will create SHA-1 fingure print

copy and paste that in google map console, it wll generate a key.use it in maps.

Comment: I generated the production key. Then i export apk with existing keystore. Still i can't see the map in the application.

Comment: From generated code in Android Studio: "Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK. You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to sign the APK for publishing."

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of Google Maps you want to use. Note that Google stopped giving away keys for the first maps version, so you'll need to use Maps V2 (or API V3).

Comment: than Ramji's answer will do the trick ;). Just put the generated key into your manifest.

Comment: Ya. I have implement in manifest. Bt still not showing map in app.