# Google Maps Api v2 key does not work properly

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, android-maps

So everything works fine with the key that i generate for me. i wanted to export the apk and did as follows:

1. generate sha-1
2. get google apikey1, include in manifest(if i run the app from eclipse directly to my phone, the map works)
3. generate keystore1 in debug mode & apk1
4. generate another sha-1 using keystore1
5. use last sha-1 to get apikey2 (include apikey2 in manifest)
6. generate keystore2 in debug mode and apk2 which i can use to install on any phone and it should work.

but it doesnt work on my phone. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

have you generate RELEASE-KEY??

hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039072/while-make-sign-apk-of-google-map-failed-to-load-map-could-not-contact-google-s/16080200#16080200) will work for you.
it helped me a lot.

you can try also [this tutorial](http://alpanpatel.blogspot.in/).

Comment: exactly this post from stackoverflow i was following. 2 times, did everything very attentively